# foreach with SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
SqlDataReader reader = getAddressQuery.sqlReader;
while (reader.Read())
{
    foreach (Object ob in reader)
    {
        someText.InnerText = someText.InnerText + " " + ob.ToString();
    }
}
```

The code in the foreach loop does not execute. However, I can do this:

```
SqlDataReader reader = getAddressQuery.sqlReader;
while (reader.Read())
{
    someText.InnerText = reader[0].ToString();
}
```

Which works.

Obviously I could achieve the same result using a regular for loop rather than a foreach loop, but I think the foreach syntax is clearer, so I use it when possible.

What has gone wrong here? Are foreach loops in c# not as flexible as in more high level languages?

Comment: I don't know for sure but I assume the foreach is iterating through each field in the recordset rather than each record...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Something like the following. Note that `IDataReader` derives from `IDataRecord` which exposes the members used to process the current row:

```
IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetFromReader(IDataReader reader)
{
    while(reader.Read()) yield return reader;
}

foreach(IDataRecord record in GetFromReader(reader))
{
    ... process it ...
}
```

Or even something like the following, to get an enumeration or list of strongly-typed entity objects from a reader:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetFromReader<T>(IDataReader reader, Func<IDataRecord, T> processRecord)
{
    while(reader.Read()) yield return processRecord(reader);
}

MyType GetMyTypeFromRecord(IDataRecord record)
{
    MyType myType = new MyType();
    myType.SomeProperty = record[0];
    ...
    return myType;
}

IList<MyType> myResult = GetFromReader(reader, GetMyTypeFromRecord).ToList();
```

**UPDATE** in response to Caleb Bell's comment.

I agree `Enumerate` is a better name.

In fact in my personal "common" library, I've now replaced the above by an extension method on `IDataReader`:

```
public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> Enumerate(this IDataReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        yield return reader;
    }
}
```

And the caller can get strongly-typed objects using:

```
reader.Enumerate.Select(r => GetMyTypeFromRecord(r))
```

Comment: That GetFromReader<T> method is nice and elegant, and it's a shame that something like that isn't in the framework natively!  I created an extension method version of it and called it Enumerate<T>.

Comment: @CalebBell - I agree `Enumerate` is a better name, see update.

Answer (score 17):

The `foreach` exposes an `IDataRecord`, which puts you in a very similar boat to the while loop:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from somewhere", conn))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var r = comm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        foreach (DbDataRecord s in r)
        {
            string val = s.GetString(0);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to see something more useful, you'll need to have some of your own code that extracts the values from the record into something more custom, as the other answer has suggested.

Either way you are going to need custom code, whether you have it inline or not or use a while loop or not depends on how often it's going to be written I suppose, any more than once and you should probably stick it in a helper method somewhere.

And to answer the somewhat question: the problem is not the `foreach`, it is your attempted usage of what it returns for you, as your comparable use of the while loop is not actually comparable.

Comment: I see. That is a bit annoying.

Comment: @Marc "wrong - SqlDataReader does implement IEnumerable" - yes, but this enumerates the columns of the (current) IDataRecord, not the rows.

Comment: @Joe on the `SqlDataReader` it appears to be returning entire records.

Comment: Even though my answer pretty much says the same as the other one, I'll leave it in for my own benefit.  I never once tried to use foreach with a reader, I always break into `while (reader.Read())` code, call it muscle memory in my fingers.  That said, the end result is very much the same so I don't feel the need to revisit old code and refactor to satiate OCD :-)

Comment: @Marc, Adam, you're right, I'd never noticed this as I always use the ADO.NET interfaces (IDataReader etc).

Comment: @Adam the internal reader implementation itself wraps the `reader.Read()` etc - so you're already doing it the most direct way, too. Likewise, I also never use `foreach` here (although these days I'd just use "dapper" and forget about it)

Comment: @MarcGravell - Is there any particular reason why the common way is to use `while(reader.Read())` and not `foreach` (they both seem to work the same so why favor one over the other)?

Comment: @BornToCode firstly that is only true of the abstract base class (DbDataReader), not the interface (IDataReader). Secondly it involves extra allocation for the iterator. Thirdly it is not obvious what it is enumerable *of*. Fourthly it allows less granularity over rows / grids and when you can / can't access metadata. Fifthly, it doesn't really help you any, as you end up accessing the data-record exactly the same as you would have the reader. Basically, Read() works fine. If you prefer foreach: that's OK too.

Answer (score 2):

you may do also that...

```
string sql = "select * from Users";
using (SqlConnection conn = GetConnection()){ 

    conn.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader rdr = new SqlCommand(sql, conn).ExecuteReader()){

           foreach (DbDataRecord c in rdr.Cast<DbDataRecord>()){
               Console.Write("{0} {1} ({2}) - ", (string)c["Name"], (string)c["Surname"], (string)c["Mail"]);
               Console.WriteLine((string)c["LoginID"]);
          }
    }
}
```